# joint density of a random variable and its bijective, differentiable function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, change-of-variable

Consider a random variable $X$ and its density function $f_{X}(x)$, consider a bijective, differentiable function $H$, and let the random variable $Y=H(X)$. I am trying to compute the joint density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$.

According to the post [Joint density of a random variable and its function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778619/joint-density-of-a-random-variable-and-its-function), $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$ when $y\neq H(x)$ (which is obvious) and $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X}(x)$ when $y=H(x)$.

I don't know why the second conclusion is true. Suppose $f_{X,Y}(x,H(x))=f_{X}(x)$, then let $y=H(x)$, we should also have $f_{X,Y}(H^{-1}(y),y)=f_{Y}(y)$, which means $f_{Y}(y)=f_{X}(H^{-1}(y))$. However, according to the change of variable, $f_{Y}(y)=f_{X}(H^{-1}(y))|\det(\frac{\partial H^{-1}(z)}{\partial z}|_{z=y})|$.

Why these two things are contradict?

Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the answer to the question you linked you'll see there is no such a thing as a density to the vector $(X,H(X))$.